# Android Studio: custom keymap file location on OSX

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, android-studio

As I'm switching often between Android Studio for Windows and Mac, I started the creation of a unified shortcut configuration to make my life easier :-)

I need save the configuration file in both platforms to restore my shortcuts in case of a full IDE re-install.

The [IntelliJ Help Page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) gave me some guidance and on Windows I found the file at Users\{my-user}\.AndroidStudioBeta\config\keymaps\{my-keymap}.xml but on Mac I don't have idea where the configurations are.

Thanks in advance (for your time and help)!

Comment: is it not `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudioBeta/keymaps/`?

Comment: Oh yes!! I used Finder but there the directory is hidden. I'll post the answer to help other Mac intrant :-)

Comment: Anyone help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333154/android-studio-same-keymap-for-windows-and-mac-os

Answer (score 11):

As pointed @zapl the configurantion can be found in

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta/keymaps/my-keymap.xml
```

Comment: Are you able to use same keymap for both windows and mac?

Answer (score 3):

Lately, I have been using Jetbrain's Toolbox application to manage my AndroidStudio versions and I was able to find them in:

`/Users/[user]/Library/ApplicationSupport/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/keymaps/myCustomKeyMap.xml`

If the folder `keymaps` does not exist you can create one.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create the directory if it does not exist already:

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.0/keymaps
```